# How to collect metrics for producer in springboot with micrometer+prometheus?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-micrometer

I am trying to collect metrics of Kafka consumers and producers using micrometer with Springboot. But not able to find the class in micrometer library.

Consumer property is :

**props.put(ConsumerConfig.METRIC_REPORTER_CLASSES_CONFIG,  "io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaConsumerMetrics”);**

but how to collect metrics for producer because  **io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaProducerApiMetrics** does not present into micrometer library.

**props.put(ConsumerConfig.METRIC_REPORTER_CLASSES_CONFIG,"io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaProducerApiMetrics”);**

Will be very thankful if someone can help.

Chetan.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka producer metrics in snapshot and recently merged

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/1835/files

Answer (score 1):

There is no such class for producer metrics

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1722

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has found this thread - both Consumer and Producer metrics use the same binder class `KafkaClientMetrics`

```
new KafkaClientMetrics(kafkaConsumer).bindTo(meterRegistry);
new KafkaClientMetrics(kafkaProducer).bindTo(meterRegistry);
```

Comment: 1+, this could be a lot better if you could add that you can register this via: `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory::addListener` and provide a proper instance for it, overriding the `producerAdded` method.